# I have a code for sample GoJS, which is not working for some reason , showing empty while loading the page

Tags: html, gojs

I have tried all possible ways to make it work . Could not able to find mistake in my code, Still getting empty page on load. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Flowchart</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gojs/1.8.35/go.js"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gojs/1.8.35/go-debug.js"/>
</head>

<body>

<div id="myDiagramDiv" style="width:400px; height:150px;"></div>
<script >
 window.onload = function () {
    var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
    var myDiagram = $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv");
    var nodeDataArray = [
     {key : "Alpha"},
     {key : "Beta"}
    ];
    var linkDataArray = [
     {to : "Beta", from: "Alpha"}
    ];
     myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(nodeDataArray , linkDataArray 
    );
  } 

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<script src="../gojs/go.js"></script>` does this actually point to a go.js file? What does the console say?

Comment: Hi Simon, Yes it points to exact go.js file. even i tried this <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gojs/1.8.35/go-debug.js"></script>

Comment: could not able to figure out why simple program is not working . tried in all browsers. no errors in console

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes here on line 12:

```
<div id="myDiagramDiv" style="width:400px; height:150px; ></div>
                                                        ^
```

And you should not self-close your `script` tags (see [To close or not to close](https://hackernoon.com/to-close-or-not-to-close-4365d24853ff) by Matias Meno).

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gojs/1.8.35/go.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gojs/1.8.35/go-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @Pierre C.   I have added the quotes , but still showing empty page.

Comment: As @Pierre C. pointed out, your script tags must be of the form: `<script src="..."></script>`.

Comment: Thanks @WalterNorthwoods. I was not sure if this was mandatory at first but it is for the `script` tags to work. I updated my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: And another problem is that if you have those two script elements, you are loading the library twice.  The first is the release version, the second is the debug version.

Comment: Hi, I am just curious if you were able to find the problem and resolve the issue. I am new to `go.js` and facing the same issue. If you have resolved then please let me know. Can you please comment your code sample that is working.

Answer (score 0):

If in case anyone is looking for the resolution then maybe it would be helpful so posting here.

You are doing couple of mistakes in your code:

1. You are loading the `<script>` with `init` function in the body after the `div` element which is wrong. you should put it in the head section.
2. You are not at all calling the `init` function on the load of the document. It should be included in the `body` tag.

Copy paste this code and test, it should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Flowchart</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/logo.jpg">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gojs/1.8.35/go.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gojs/1.8.35/go-debug.js"></script>
        <script>
            function init() {
                var $               =   go.GraphObject.make;
                var myDiagram       =   $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv");
                var nodeDataArray   =   [
                                            {key : "Alpha"},
                                            {key : "Beta"}
                                        ];
                                        
                var linkDataArray   =   [
                                         {to : "Beta", from: "Alpha"}
                                        ];
                myDiagram.model     =   new go.GraphLinksModel(nodeDataArray , linkDataArray);
            } 

         </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="init()">
        <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid black"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```